# How can split column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

in my table i have a column `current_date` the value is 2012-11-27.

heres my code

```
$query = QModel::query("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE current_date='$order_date'");
```

The value of `$order_date` is year-month only "*2012-10*", how can i split the `current_date` into year-month only "*2012-10*"...

should I use `CHARINDEX` to split the current_date??? how please...

thanks

Comment: what rdbms you are using? mysql? oracle? sqlserver? *etc*..

Comment: Check the intervall `current_date >= '2012-10-01' and current_date < '2012-11-01'`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson exactly my answer. Others answers are using functions over columns and that's bad practice depending on my experience

Comment: Use DatePart function in MSSQL

Comment: here my code $query = QModel::query("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE current_date='$order_date'"); the value of $order_date is year and month only 2012-10, how can i split the current date into year and month only 2012-10... sorry for bad english...

Comment: I got it now $query = QModel::query("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(current_date,'-',2)='$order_date'"); YEHEY :D

Comment: `current_date` is a reserved word, do **not** use it as a column name! And you should ***not*** store a date in a character column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you need to select all records within one month you can do follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE current_date >= convert(datetime, '20121001', 112) and current_date < convert(datetime, '20121101', 112)
```

I cannot advice to use `month` and `year` functions because your indexes will not work

**update:** AFAIK, in MySQL it will be

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE current_date >= str_to_date('20121001', '%y%m%d') and current_date < str_to_date('20121101', '%y%m%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `MySQL`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE YEAR(current_date) = 2012 AND
      MONTH(current_date) = 10
```

for `SQL Server`

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE DATEPART(year,current_date) = 2012 AND
      DATEPART(month, current_date) = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Works for mysql as well as sql server

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE month(current_date)=10
and   year(current_date)=2012
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL try this:

```
select * 
from table
where datepart(year, current_date) = 2012
    and datepart(month, current_date) = 10
```